# kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm

Tags: kerberos, ubuntu-server

it's been a couple days that i am hitting my head against the wall with this problem, and nothing works, i'm in one VirtualBox and i don't no anymore where to go with that.
I'm using the Ubuntu Server

thats its the problem:

```
kinit: Cannot find KDC for realm "XXXXXX.LOCAL" while getting initial credentials
```

krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = XXXXXX.LOCAL
        dns_lookup_realm = false
        dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
OPAQUE.LOCAL = {
        default_domain = xxxxxxx.local
}

[domain_realm]
        opqserver = XXXXXX.LOCAL
```

```
klist: No credentials cache found (filename: /tmp/krb5cc_1000)
```

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver XX.XX.XX.179
domain XXXXXX.LOCAL
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

i tried to change inside de krb5.conf with:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = XXXXXX.LOCAL
        dns_lookup_realm = true
        dns_lookup_kdc = true

        forward = true
        forwardable = true

[realms]
OPAQUE.LOCAL = {
        default_domain = xxxxxxx.local
        kdc = XXXXX.LOCAL
        

}

[domain_realm]
        opqserver = XXXXXX.LOCAL
```